# How to fix shell bash mysql load query syntax error?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I need a shell script to load data into mysql db. The script is the next:

```
# !bin/bash

qry="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_x;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_x AS SELECT * FROM x.y LIMIT 0;
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/xxx.csv' 
    INTO TABLE tmp_x 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\," 
    ENCLOSED BY "\""
    LINES TERMINATED BY "\\n"
    IGNORE 1 ROWS;"

mysql --host=xxx --user=xxx --password=xxx db << EOF 
$qry
EOF
```

I get the following error message:

> *ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '*
>   *ENCLOSED BY "*
>
> *LINES TERMINATED BY \n*
>
> *IGNORE 1 ROWS' at line 3*

I think it is something to do escaping some character, I tried changing to single quotes but it does not work neither.

I am workin on `Ubuntu 18`.

Any help will be very grateful.

Comment: Why not just put the query directly in the heredoc? Quote the heredoc (`<<'EOF'` instead of `<<EOF`) and it's completely literal -- the shell doesn't change anything in its contents at all.

Comment: BTW, if you want to *see* how your variable was parsed with the current code, just `printf '%s\n' "$qry"` and then compare it to what you know is good/working SQL.

Comment: probably you need to escape double quotes of `"\,"` , otherwise string will end after encountering first double quote. Also you shebang seems wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql --host=xxx --user=xxx --password=xxx db << EOF 
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_x;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_x AS SELECT * FROM x.y LIMIT 0;
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/xxx.csv' 
    INTO TABLE tmp_x 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS;
EOF
```

If you really must use a variable, you'll need to play with quoting:

```
#!/bin/bash

qry="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_x;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_x AS SELECT * FROM x.y LIMIT 0;
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/xxx.csv' 
    INTO TABLE tmp_x 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY \",\" 
    ENCLOSED BY \"\\\"\"
    LINES TERMINATED BY \"\\n\"
    IGNORE 1 ROWS;"

mysql --host=xxx --user=xxx --password=xxx db << EOF 
$qry
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be troublesome to use double-quoted strings in your SQL, since you're using double-quotes as the string delimiter in bash. In other words, which is the double-quote that ends the bash string, and which should be treated as a literal double-quote character in the SQL?

To resolve this, use single-quotes for string delimiters in the SQL.

Another issue: There's no need to put a backslash before `,` for the field terminator.

Another issue: The `\n` needs another backslash.

Here's what I tried and it seems to work:

```
qry="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_x;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_x AS SELECT * FROM x.y LIMIT 0;
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/xxx.csv'
    INTO TABLE tmp_x
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS;"
```

I only printed the query, I haven't tested running it.